# Playframework 2.3.9 dependency override

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

As of Play 2.3, Play is added as an SBT Plugin as follows in my `Build.scala` as follows:

```
Project("root", file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication).

I need a specific dependeny updated, namely Fluentlenium (Play 2.3.9 still uses 0.9.3):

```
"org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % "0.10.3"
```

How can I replace the old version and replace it with a newer one? Simply adding the library to the `libraryDependencies` leaves me with both versions in the class path.

---

Edit: After digging a bit deeper, it seems as if the (new?) feature of `dependencyOverrides` that comes with SBT 13.8 could be a solution:

[Overriding a version](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version). But also have a look at [Conflict Management](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Conflict+Management) from the very same documentation.

With this you can override single dependencies, which means that you have to override each transititve dependency manually.

Comment: Just remove already existing fluentlenium 0.9.3 in your local repository folder and try again

Comment: That's not how it works, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> Simply adding the library to the `libraryDependencies` leaves me with both versions in the class path.

Are you sure about this? sbt (Ivy) should evict the older one if there are multiple versions in the same configuration.

In most cases

```
libraryDependencies += "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % "0.10.3"
```

should be ok, granted that 0.9.x are binary compatible with 0.10.x. If you want to make sure that it is overridden during transitive dependency resolution, `dependencyOverrides` might be the way to go:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % "0.10.3"
```